# autopostback event will fire for textbox when java script desable at client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hi all i have set autopostback property for text box . will it fire when java script desable at client side

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Slider1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Slider1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"  >
```

Comment: When JavaScript disables...what? Are you disabling the TextBox? The OnTextChanged event? Something else?

Comment: no i have written some stuff when OnTextChanged on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not when you change the value from javascript. But however when the value is changed , OnTextChanged event might be called when your page does postback from any other button